# How to convert shell output of 'df' command into a dictionary?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I need to convert the output of `df` command into a python dictionary format.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1987884        0   1987884   0% /dev
tmpfs             402060     1992    400068   1% /run
tmpfs             402060     1992    400068   1% /run
/dev/sda6      113960124 37751712  70376476  35% /
```

My required format is:

`[{'Filesystem':udev, 'Used':0, 'Available':1987884 ,'Use%':0%, 'Mounted_On':'/dev'},{'Filesystem':udev, 'Used':0, 'Available':1987884 ,'Use%':0%, 'Mounted_On':'/dev'}]`

I tried to implement this:

```
path='df -h'
p = Popen(path, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = p.stdout.read().decode()  # from bytes to str
header, data, _*= output.split('\n')  # split to lines
header = header.replace('Mounted on', 'Mounted_on')  # fix a two word field
df = dict(list(zip(header.split(), data.split())))  # split to fields and combine
return df
```

But it return only the first row only:

`{'Filesystem': 'udev', 'Size': '1.9G', 'Used': '0', 'Avail': '1.9G', 'Use%': '0%', 'Mounted_on': '/dev'}`

May I know what is missing code. I think some logical mistakes in it.

Comment: `header, data, _= output.split('\n')` you are trying to unpack three values, seems you get only two

Comment: Edited my question it is now cleared

Comment: I'm getting only the first records

Comment: The current code with `*=` is an SyntaxError. And please show the full error message including location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is here:

```
header, data, _= output.split('\n')
```

This will unpack first line of `output` into `header`, second into `data`, third into `_` - but you have more than 3 lines, and most likely you want all of them (except the header) in `data`, so:

```
header, *data = output.splitlines()
```

But this also requires changing

```
df = dict(list(zip(header.split(), data.split())))
```

to

```
df = [ dict(zip(header.split(), datarow.split())) for datarow in data ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Blotosmetek